# How do I get a delay between putting a ImageIcon on a JButton?

Tags: java, swing

The method placePiece correctly places an ImageIcon on a JButton. I would like the image to remain there for one second and then be replaced with a different colored ImageIcon.  The problem with the following code is that the red ImageIcon never appears.  The delay takes place and then the black ImageIcon appears. I would like the red ImageIcon to appear, then have a 1 second delay, and then the black one appear.  Thanks in advance for any help.

```
placePiece(0, 3, "red");
//delay 1 second here
try 
{
    Thread.sleep(1000);
}
catch (Exception exc)  { }
placePiece(0, 3, "black");
```

Comment: `Swing` program is a single threaded program.

Comment: Instead of `Thread.sleep()` try using a [`Swing Timer`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/Timer.html)

Comment: As an aside, why is it that you've [asked 11 questions](http://stackoverflow.com/users/975972/gil?tab=questions), every one of which has at least one answer, two of which have two, yet there is only **one *accepted* answer** among them?  If I was getting correct answers to less than 10% of my questions, I'd probably be looking for another venue to ask questions (or asking better questions).

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest you using Java's `javax.swing.Timer`.

There is a tutorial here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html

In the timer, you can easily get the interval by setting it in the parameter under `speed` as shown below.

```
int speed = 1000;  //delay of 1 second
timer = new Timer(speed, obj);
```

---

Further more, when you use `Thread.sleep(1000)`, there is no guarantee that it will always be delayed by 1 second.

Answer (score 2):

You may use like

```
placePiece(0, 3, "red");
int delay = 1000; 
 ActionListener taskPerformer = new ActionListener() {
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
      placePiece(0, 3, "black");
  }
};
new Timer(delay, taskPerformer).start();
```

`Thread.sleep()` is not good practice with swing.